In Nextjs 14, how can I internationalize the project with the new structure inside src/app?
I have the default layout.tsx and page.tsx files. For the project I am doing I don't need anything else and it will be Client Side so I would like to know how to configure i18n so that in the page.tsx file I can use translations.
I don't need the router or anything related to the urls, I just need to use the t() function to be able to show the messages in the indicated language.
In the public/locales folder I have the language json files.
I have this i18n configuration in the next-i18next.config.mjs file:
export default {
  i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'es',
    locales: ['en', 'es'],
    localeDetection: false,
  },
};

and this in the next.config.mjs file:
import nextI18NextConfig from './next-i18next.config.mjs';

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  i18n: nextI18NextConfig.i18n,
};

export default nextConfig;

What should I have in layout.tsx and/or page.tsx for the translations to work?
I have searched the internet and there is no example of what I want to achieve.

Imo this question is prone to opinionated answers. I'ld advice you to go with this example. If you want to represent the language in the url, you can go with the dynamic routes and a [lng] segment.
